# Vue.JS: turn every matching case to a hyperlink

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to turn every matching case from an array to a link

```
// I call the message component using this from another component

<ul>
     <li 
          v-for="message in message"
          v-bind:message="message"
          is="message"
</ul>

// in the message component I have a mounted that reads the text message
// from the server and filters hashtags

data () {
  return {
    hashtagsInMessages: ''
  };
},

mounted () {    
  const filterMessageHashtags = _.filter( this.message,text.split( ' ' ), value => hashtags.indexOf(value) != -1 );

  this.hashtagsInMessages = filterMessageHashtags;
}
```

**With this, how can I turn a message to a link, for instance:**

hey how you doing #cool #fire #water bro?

**To this, using Vue.js**

hey how you doing [#cool](http://www.cool.com) [#fire](http://www.fire.com) [#water](http://www.water.com) bro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```js
Vue.component("message-el", {
    template: "#message",
    props: ["message"],
    created: function (){
        this.messages = this.message.split(" ");
        this.hashTags = this.messages.filter(function (message){
            return message[0] === "#";
        });
    },
    data: function (){
        return {
            messages: [],
            hashTags: [],
        };
    },
    methods: {

    }
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: function (){
        return {

        }
    },
    methods: {

    }
});
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <message-el message="this is a message #tag1 #tag2">

  </message-el>
</div>

<div id="message" class="none">
  <div>
    <div>
      <template v-for="message in messages">
          <a v-if="hashTags.indexOf(message) > -1" :href="'#' + message">
              {{ message }}
          </a>
          <span v-else>
              {{ message }}
          </span>
          &nbsp
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```