# Convert string to vNode vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a string similar to this one saved on the DB:

```
Lorem #ipsum dolor sit amet, #consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do #eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

As you can see some words are hashtags (#ipsum).

What I'm trying to achieve is to render the string in a `span` and put all the hashtags in a clickable link.

So far what I did is this:

```
let caption = ref(props.caption); // the text above
const tagRegex = /(#+[a-zA-Z0-9(_)]{1,})/g;

caption.value = caption.value.replace(tagRegex, `<a href="/$1">$1</a>`);

return () => h("span", { "innerHTML": caption.value, class: "text-pre" });
```

This is working as expected, I can see the text and all clickable `a` to the relative hashtag.

The second step is to replace `a` with `router-link` (Vue Router) and the `href` to `to`.

Trying to simply replace them doesn't work. The DOM render the `router-link` but unfortunately it is not compiled and does nothing.

I tried to replace `innerHTML` with `v-html` but it doesn't work.

I tried to create multiple nodes using children, but even here I failed.

Do you know how can I achieve the result? Thanks

Comment: Representing elements as strings like "<a href" is a wrong direction. Just stick to using h() everywhere. There likely will be an array of them in your case. Usually this is done with v-for in a template

Comment: It would be nice to see an example based on my question as an answer, thanks

Comment: It's supposed to be something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871967/vue-js-turn-every-matching-case-to-a-hyperlink

Answer (score 1):

I don't know weither you use Vue 3 or 2 but I am guessing Vue 3.
This is a quick example of router-links dynamically created inside a text.

[Vue 3 Example with dynamic components](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-text-router-links-mpdmch)

It is not necessary to use a render function for this. With the `<component>`-component you can dynamically create components by providing the `is` prop.
If you want to use the render function you can map the sections to VNodes using the `h` function